# Why $x$ should be **real**

Tags: gamma-function

Show that if $x$ is **real** and positive ($x \in \mathbb{R}^{>  0}$) then:
$$Γ(x)= ∫_0^1(- \ln ⁡t )^{x-1}  dt $$

---

**Solution** :

First recall the gamma function:

$$Γ(x)= ∫_0^∞ e^{-t} t^{x-1}  dt \; \; \;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;  \;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;  (1) $$

Let $u = e^{-t}$

$$\ln u = -t \rightarrow  t = - \ln u \;\;\; $$and$$ \;\;\; dt = - \frac{1}{u} du$$

then we can rewrite equation $(1)$ in the new form of below:

$$Γ(x)= ∫_0^1(-\ln⁡ u )^{x-1}  du $$

and the solution is completed.

---

I can justify why $x$ must be positive but I don't know where realness of $x$ is needed?

Any Ideas?

Comment: It is not needed.

Comment: @Did humm, but Why?!

Comment: Umm... you were surprised $x$ is supposed to be real, and asked why does it have to be. Not sure what kind of answer do you want now.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can remember (but I shall not be able to prove it),$x$ could be any real or complex number provided that $\Re(x)>0$.

Using a CAS, I computed the integral using $x=a+i b$. The result was $\Gamma (a+i b+1)$ under the conditions $\Re(a)+1>\Im(b)$.

Comment: Just to state the obvious, the condition the CAS gave is equivalent to $\Re x>-1$.

Comment: @CarstenSchultz. Yes, I bet ! Cheers.